# Powershell Array within Runas-Command

Tags: powershell, passwords, runas

I wanted to write a little Script to check who has default credentials in my domain.
For checking I wanted to use the runas-command (because I don´t know it better :D).
I wrote the following script:

```bsh
$pw = @("aaaaa","54321","12345");
$user = @("user1", "user2", "user3")
$domain = "mydomain"

for ($usercount = 0; $usercount -le $user.Length-1; $usercount++)
{
    for ($i = 0;$i -le $pw.Length-1; $i++)
    {
        runas /user=""$($domain)\$($user[$usercount])"" /password=""$($pw[$i])"" .\test.bat
        Write-Host "runas /user=""$($domain)\$($user[$usercount])"" /password=""$($pw[$i])"" .\test.bat"
    }
}
```

and the output looks nice but it won´t work...

```
runas /user="mydomain\user1" /password="aaaaa" .\test.bat
runas /user="mydomain\user1" /password="54321" .\test.bat
runas /user="mydomain\user1" /password="12345" .\test.bat
runas /user="mydomain\user2" /password="aaaaa" .\test.bat
runas /user="mydomain\user2" /password="54321" .\test.bat
runas /user="mydomain\user2" /password="12345" .\test.bat
runas /user="mydomain\user3" /password="aaaaa" .\test.bat
runas /user="mydomain\user3" /password="54321" .\test.bat
runas /user="mydomain\user3" /password="12345" .\test.bat
```

would be great if somebody could help me out with this one :-)

Comment: What I would suggest you do, is determine what the correct command line is for running your batch files using the `runas` command. Once you've done that and checked that it works from a batch file, try and write your PowerShell commands so that it outputs the correct data. At the moment you appear to be expecting us to correct your resulting file content, without telling us what that content is supposed to be. As the question is a PowerShell issue, not a batch one, I've removed your [[tag:batch-file]] tag.

Comment: what is the actual thing you are trying to achieve? not what your code is trying to do ... _what is the reason you are trying to do that_?

Comment: it´s becaue I wanted to know who is using a default password and I would like to inform those persons.

Comment: You shouldn't do this. By simply trying out various passwords on a user account will block those users.

Answer (score 0):

Just do an `iex`:

```bsh
$pw = @("aaaaa","54321","12345");
$user = @("user1", "user2", "user3")
$domain = "mydomain"

for ($usercount = 0; $usercount -le $user.Length-1; $usercount++)
{
    for ($i = 0;$i -le $pw.Length-1; $i++)
    {
        iex "runas /user:""$($domain)\$($user[$usercount])"" /password:""$($pw[$i])"" .\test.bat"
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn´t work either. I guess iex has some problems with the runas command. I just tried out the following code and it also didn´t work and I guess this one should be correct...

iex "C:\Windows\System32\runas /user:""mydomain\myuser"" /password:""password"" ""C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe"""

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I programmed it using C# via ValidateCredentials. Should be more reliable